# how to remove a string in a line of Multiline textbox c#

Tags: c#, string, textbox, multiline

i have the data bellow in my multiline textbox in my form

[image]

what i want is remove  the " -" from that line, i wanna just to remove in that first line but without changing the rest of textbox values

what i have tried but without sucess

```
Textbox1.Lines[0] = Textbox1.Lines[0].Replace(" -", "");
```

Comment: `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Lines[0] + "\r\n", textBox1.Lines[0].Replace(" -", "") + "\r\n");` would work, but beware of duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=netcore-3.1) for the `Lines` property:

> **Note**
>
> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines in the [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netcore-3.1). To get a writable collection of lines, use code similar to the following: `textBox1.Lines = new string[] { "abcd" };`

So, it seems we need to assign it a whole new array, not just modify an existing array value.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
var newLines = Textbox1.Lines;                // Capture the read-only array locally
newLines[0] = newLines[0].Replace(" -", "");  // Now we can modify a value
Textbox1.Lines = newLines;                    // And reassign it to our textbox
```